# Serilog middleware not working properly with error handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, .net-core, serilog

I create middleware about logging the errors with Serilog. And I love it because it's simple and maintainable. Here it is:

```
public class LogContextMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public LogContextMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {           
        LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", context.User.Identity.Name);
        LogContext.PushProperty("ApiPath", context.Request.Path);
        return next(context);
    }
}
```

Then I thought that I can put an error handling mechanism here. And this class turned into:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var isAdmin = context.User.Identity.Name == "Admin" ? true : false;
        var errorId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
        {
            Title = "An error has occurred",
            Status = 500,
            Detail = isAdmin ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : "Please contact us for details",
            Instance = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };

        LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", context.User.Identity.Name);
        LogContext.PushProperty("ApiPath", context.Request.Path);
        LogContext.PushProperty("ErrorId", errorId);

        _emailService.SendMail(new EmailDto
        {
            To = new List<string>() { "mail@mail.com" },
            Body = ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : ex.ToString(),
            Subject = "Error!" + context.Request.ToString()
        });

        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        context.Response.WriteJson(problemDetails, "application/problem+json");
    }
}
```

But when I run the application, I see that the application does not write the logs to the database.

Here is Serilog configuration:

```
var appSettings = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
.Build();

var sinkOpts = new SinkOptions { TableName = "_Log", AutoCreateSqlTable = true, BatchPostingLimit = 10 };
var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions
{
    AdditionalColumns = new Collection<SqlColumn>
    {
        new SqlColumn
            {ColumnName = "UserName", PropertyName = "UserName", DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, DataLength = 64},

        new SqlColumn
            {ColumnName = "ApiPath", PropertyName = "ApiPath", DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, NonClusteredIndex = true},

        new SqlColumn
            {ColumnName = "ErrorId", PropertyName = "ErrorId", DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,DataLength = 36 }
    }
};
columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.MessageTemplate);
columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties);

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
    connectionString: appSettings.GetConnectionString("DB"),
    sinkOptions: sinkOpts,
    columnOptions: columnOptions,
    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error
).CreateLogger();
```

I can't find where I made a mistake and I need your help.

Comment: Probably connection string has been overridden somewhere in appsettings.json?

Comment: Not getting entries in a database can be any reason, why do you think it is related to the code you have shown? Try to reduce it to a simpler logic and add debugging details.

Comment: May not be directly related to your issue, but the return value of `LogContext.PushProperty()` generally needs to be disposed, e.g. via a `using` statement. HTH!